# How to show only those assets corresponding to a particular location in maximo?

Tags: maximo

I have list of locations and also list of assets, But i just want to display only those assets corresponding to the location selected by user in custom application. Please guide how this cascading will be done.

Comment: The functionality is already in Maximo. You go to Assets > Locations. When you look up a location, go into detailed record view, there is another tab for assets. What is that you are doing that is unique?

Answer (score 0):

Define a relationship in database configuration for your asset object relating its corresponding field to location corresponding field. Give this relationship any name.
E.g 
If attribute in asset object is called loc and attribute in location object is storename .
Then relationship query should be like
loc =:storename

Then in application designer,  check table properties and in its relationship field enter the relationship name you defined in previous step.
Now log out and log in. It should work